# Satchmo install on a mac using virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv, satchmo

I have virtualenv set up and working correctly on my mac os (leopard) running python 2.6 & django 1.2.3. I want to install Satchmo but I haven't found solid instructions for a mac install using virtualenv. Can anyone help regarding this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using buildout with virtualenv then try this: https://github.com/shywolf9982/satchmo-buildout

Of course installing newest XCode ie. 3.1 or 3.2 is a must..

Unfortunatelly compiniling stuff on Mac can give you the creeps... My collegue and I, were fighting 12h with installation of geodjango on Spatialite database, and we didn't make it after all :)

If you're not using buildout then just use macports for installing modules listed in above repo's `buildout.cfg` file.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[This Satchmo Project post](https://www.satchmoproject.com/blog/2010/aug/01/satchmo-virtualenv/) contains the instructions I follow on Snow Leopard. I use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and/or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) in lieu of the Debian package tools.